# Find rows with the maximum number of common relations in a many to many relationship

Tags: sql

I have a `games` table that store games detail (`gameId, name, description`), and a `category` table with two columns `catId, name`, and a `game_category` table (`id, game_id, category_id`), which relates each game with the categories it belongs to.

The relations in tables are fixed, so I want to find related games (most similar) based on the number of shared categories with a particular game. The result must order by higher similarity

Comment: Read about joins, have a try, come back if you have problems. Like this it's unclear where you actually have a problem.

Comment: Tnx for answer fancyPants, I want to have a suggestion system, means when I show a game, some of similar games that have same category(categories) shown! the result must order by most similarity!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is look for other games which have the maximum categories in common with the reference game. To do so, get all the categories of the reference game, and count the number of categories shared with each other game. The ones with the higher number of common categories should be the most similar:

```
SELECT SimCG.gameId, COUNT(*) NumberOfSharedCategories
   -- count of categories of similar games
FROM dbo.CategoryGame AS RG
   -- table of reference game
INNER JOIN dbo.CategoryGame AS SimCG
   -- table of similar games
ON RG.categoryId = SimCG.categoryId 
   -- common categories shared by reference and similar games
WHERE 
   RG.gameId = 1 
       -- Id of the refenece game
   AND SimCG.gameId <> 1
       -- Exclude the reference game from the compared games
GROUP BY SimCG.gameId
   -- Group by similar game id
```

You can easyly use this base query to join to the games table, and order by the `NumberOfSharedCategories` column, in descending order.